# How do I prove an inequality of a strict concave function?

Tags: functions

The function $f(x)$ is strict concave, strict increasing, and $f(0) = 0$. $a, b \in \mathbf R \; and \; a < b$, how can I get that $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{f(a)}{f(b)}$?

Thank you!

Oh sorry I forgot to mention that  $f:\mathbf R_{+} \rightarrow \mathbf R_{+}$ is continuous; and $a, b$ are positive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of concave, assuming $0\lt a\lt b$,
$$
f(a)\gt f(0)\frac{b-a}{b}+f(b)\frac ab
$$
Divide by $f(b)$ (which is positive by hypothesis):
$$
\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}\gt\frac{a}{b}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{bf(a)-af(b)}{bf(b)}$. Now, $bf(b)>0\forall b\in \mathbb{R}$ since $f(\cdot)$ is increasing and $f(0)=0$. Now, $$bf(a)-af(b)=(b-a)f(a)-a(f(b)-f(a))$$ For concave functions, if $f$ is differentiable, $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ $$f(y)\le f(x)+(y-x)f'(x)$$ So, $$f(b)-f(a)<(b-a)f'(a)\\
-f(a)=f(0)-f(a)<-af'(a)$$ Hence, $$bf(a)-af(b)>(b-a)(f(a)-af'(a))>0$$

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: When I answered this, there was no mention that $a,b$ are positive, so I had to assume $f$ is differentiable. If $a,b$ are positive then @robjohn has a given a nice proof for that.